# How can I assign value returned from anon function?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

Is it possible to avoid declaring global variable and instead assign it the result of the anonymous function?

```
var logged = false;
Ext.each(userRecords, function (userRecord) {
  if (userRecord.get('id') == currentuser) {
    if (userRecord.get('password') == currentuserpassword) {
      logged = true;
    }
  }
});
```

Example:

```
var logged = Ext.each(userRecords, function (userRecord) {
  if (userRecord.get('id') == currentuser) {
    if (userRecord.get('password') == currentuserpassword) {
      return true;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: That function is a callback, so the return value is whatever `Ext.each` returns.

Comment: even if it's anon, it's still a function and works pretty much like any other one, so as @elclanrs said return 1;

Comment: Sounds like you need [`Ext.some`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Array-method-some) rather than `Ext.each`. Learn your tools.

Comment: @elclanrs no, the issue is he wants _one_ return value for the whole `.each` instead of one for each iteration.  He's using the wrong API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Ext JS 4.0 or later, just replace your `Ext.each` in the second code block with [`Ext.Array.some`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Array-method-some) and your code will work as is.

> Executes the specified function for each array element until the function returns a truthy value. If such an item is found, the function will return true immediately. Otherwise, it will return false.

Answer (score 0):

Using ECMAScript 5 [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) array method:

```
var logged = userRecords.some(function (userRecord) {
  if (userRecord.get('id') == currentuser) {
    if (userRecord.get('password') == currentuserpassword) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: `Ext.Array.some` is built into Ext JS - no ES5 required.